# How to process RDD as a map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to Scala and Spark and I got stuck with this *simple* problem which I have no idea how to solve.

Namely, I have 2 RDDs, let's name them `tx_inputs` and `input_tx`.

They have the following declarations:

`tx_inputs` is RDD of 2-tuples with form `(tx_1, [input1, input2, ...])` where `[]` brackets denote Set. Keys (`tx_1, tx_2.., tx_n`) are unique. But `tx_k` in associated list can contain one or more `input` from `tx_j` (where j != k)

`input_tx` is RDD of 2-tuples with form `(input_n, false)`. Here keys are inputs and they are unique.

What I want to do is implement the following pseudocode, i.e. yield the same results:

```
do{

changeHappened=false

for (tx, inputs) from tx_inputs:
    if (inputs.length == 1):
        input_tx(inputs[0]) = tx
        tx_inputs.remove(tx)
        changeHappened = true

removeAllLabeledInputs(tx_inputs, input_tx)        
} while(changeHappened)
```

Where `removeAllLabeledInputs` should remove every `input` from all the sets (values) in `tx_inputs` which is not labeled as `false` in `input_tx`.

All values are `String`. I'm using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.2.1

p.s. In case I wasn't clear enough, here is a small example:

In the beginning, we have the following situation:

```
tx_inputs:

(tx_1, [input1, input2]),
(tx_2, [input1]),
(tx_3, [input3, input4, input1])


inputx_tx:

(input1, false),
(input2, false),
(input3, false), 
(input4, false)
```

And in the end of the algorithm we have :

```
tx_inputs:

(tx_3, [input3, input4])


inputx_tx:

(input1, tx_2),
(input2, tx_1),
(input3, false), 
(input4, false)
```

Comment: The logic looks inherently sequential and given immutable nature of Spark's data structures, won't work well, unless you have pretty strong restrictions on the input.

Comment: This is not what RDD's are designed for. Simple answer - Please don't use RDD.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks! I thought this could be done with RDDs, but I won't use it then. Once again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!